# ASP Classic: twitter and facebook autoposting without signing in

Tags: facebook, twitter, asp-classic, posting

In work I got a task (we MUST work with ASP Classic by the way): when user posts a blog, a link to that blog should be posted automatically on user's facebook timeline and in his twitter. I made everything working, but there is one problem: user needs to be signed in to post. I've made the cheking if he's logged in, and if not he must log in.
But I need to avoid the logging-in step and make it automatic (by sending user's username and password as part of the data sent to twitter/facebook or something like that), but I can't figure out how to do that or if it's even possible at all.

Any ideas? Would greatly appreciate any help.

P.S.: for the twitter part I used http://scottdesapio.com/VBScriptOAuth/
for the facebook part I used a combination of: http://snipplr.com/view/61108/facebook-app-login--authorization-entirely-clientside/

Everything works, but is it possible to automatize the user's sign-in part?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to make the both things automated...
The problem with Twitter was that I didn't store request token in session, that's why I got "Could not authenticate you" error.
Can't remember what I did wrong with Facebook (some co-workers helped me out), but I guess I didn't make proper http requests...
So the answer is: yes, it is possible to automatically post to Twitter and Facebook without user sign in.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong then your logged in user in facebook for current browser is not authorize for your app.

I think you should try googling about "How to authorize users into app". OR

If you don't mind I am giving you the direct URL to go to that setting page for your app:
https://developers.facebook.com/apps and then go to your app then after from left side bar go to roles and then after click on test user tab from top of page and then click on add button it will opne one pop-up to add a user.

In app you have to add test user for testing purpose and have to login for that added test user, so added user will be authorize for that app and you will be able to test.

Thank you...

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: hello skumar I have verified that link and then writed on here you are right it can be expire but for now it is working. Thank you.